# IF expression contains unexpected numeric - can code be shortened

Tags: python

Wondering if this can be simplified:

```
sp = subprocess.Popen(['lipc-get-prop', 'com.lab126.wifid', 'cmState'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
response, _ = sp.communicate()
if  response.find("CONNECTED") > -1:
    wifi = 'CONNECTED'
elif response.find("PENDING") > -1:
    wifi = 'PENDING'
elif response.find("READY") > -1:
    wifi = 'READY'
elif response.find("NA") > -1:
    wifi = 'NA'
```

I would prefer something like wifi = response.
Printing response gives the expected text, but using it in an IF statement, the value is numeric, giving the starting location of the text in the string. Is there a one line version to assign wifi the text value?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is the proper way to do it, whats the problem?

Comment: More Pythonic would be `if 'CONNECTED' in response:`

Comment: Fundamentally, the goal is to check whether the string is any one of a fixed set of strings; as long as it is, we assign it to `wifi`. Please see the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression.

```
import re

match = re.search(r'CONNECTED|PENDING|READY|NA', response)
if match:
    wifi = match.group(0)
```

This isn't a one-liner because you need to check whether any of the words were found. If you know it will contain one of them, you can use:

```
wifi = re.search(r'CONNECTED|PENDING|READY|NA', response).group(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
wifi = [x for x in ["CONNECTED","PENDING","READY","NA",""] if x in response][0]
```

Note that it extends your code with:

```
else:
    wifi = ''
```